# Lattices without prime ideals

Tags: lattice-theory

If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, is there a lattice $L$ of cardinality $\kappa$ such that $L$ contains no prime ideals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - set $L:=\kappa+2$ and endow it with the following ordering:

- $\kappa < \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \kappa$;
- $\kappa+1 > \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \kappa$.

(Essentially this is an infinite version of the non-distributive lattice $M_3$ with a $\kappa$-antichain.)

The only proper ideal is the singleton consisting of the bottom element. But this ideal is not prime as the meet of any two members of $\kappa$ equals the bottom element.

Comment: The principal ideals generated by any $\alpha\in\kappa$ are all prime.

Comment: Ah, sorry: they are meet-irreducible, but not prime. However, they are most definitely proper ideals, so they need to be dealt with in the answer in one way or another.